# question related to measurability of set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset E\subset B$ , where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of finite Lebesgue measure and $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $E$ is also Lebesgue measurable if $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$ .

My attempt:-
since $A$ is measurable then for any $C \subset R$ we have :-
$$ \mu(C) \ge \mu ( C\cap A) + \mu(C \cap A')$$ 
$$\ge \mu(C\cap E)+\mu( C\cap B')$$
$$\ge \mu(C\cap E)+ \mu (C\cap E')$$
Hence $E$ is measurable , my attempt based on this :-

if $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$ then $\mu(A\cap E)=\mu(B\cap E)$
so is my attempt is right and did what I used is correct ?and if there is different way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Measure of $A-B$ is zero, hence its subsets are measurable

Comment: so you mean $E= A \cup (E-A)$,and since $A \in M$ and $ E-A \subset B-A$ then $E-A$ is measurable ( because our measure space is complete) , also we have $M$ is $\sigma$-algebra, that is $E$ is measurable.

Comment: Yea, that's right

Comment: thanks for your useful comment, it give me more insight about the problem.but I still have the question if $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$ then $\mu(A\cap E) =\mu(B\cap E)$ in general.

Comment: Do you assume here that A is subset of B? Coz otherwise that's not true

Comment: No,the only condition its they have the same finite measure .

Comment: What about A and B disjoint and E is A?

Comment: $E$ is arbitrary in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: My previous comment was a counterexample

Comment: Oh... sorry, Now I understand.